# Gitlab get count of not Work in progress merge requests

Tags: ruby, gitlab

to get count of all merge requests assigned to user on Gitlab:

```
current_user.assigned_merge_requests.opened.count
```

to get count of all opened merge requests:

```
MergeRequest.opened.count
```

How I can get count of all opened merge requests but not marked as "Work in progress"???